# How do bots access directories on a server that are not DocumentRoot of public IP address? How do I stop them?

Tags: networking, dns, ip, virtual-host

I have a local network set up with apache2 and "named" running on OpenSuse 13.1 Linux.

I used the "named" service to use my computer as a domain server. I set up my router to point to ask my computer for domain lookups, so I have a chance to have it rewrite a bunch of domains on my network to its own local IP, 192.168.0.111

This works great.

I use virtual host configuration to allow various domains and subdomains (re-routed to the same IP via named) to pull up different directories in my computer.

**UPDATE -- (added base domain VirtualHost info)**
For my domains:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 192.168.0.111
    ServerAlias for.us 192.168.0.111
    DocumentRoot /home/personal/network/for.us

    # if not specified, the global error log is used
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/for.us-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/for.us-access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 192.168.0.111
    ServerAlias wa.net 192.168.0.111
    DocumentRoot /home/work/wa.net

    # if not specified, the global error log is used
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/ip-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/ip-access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And then for my subdomains:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 192.168.0.111
    ServerAlias fmb.wa.net
    DocumentRoot /home/work/wa.net/fmb
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 192.168.0.111
    ServerAlias postrecord.wa.net
    DocumentRoot /home/work/wa.net/postrecord
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 192.168.0.111
    ServerAlias cvalley.wa.net
    DocumentRoot /home/work/wa.net/cvalley_local
</VirtualHost>
```

This makes it possible for me to hit cvalley.wa.net from any device in my network and get the site that lives in /home/work/wa.net/cvalley_local

I decided to forward port 80 to this computer, so I could share a few development sites with coworkers. I can't control which site they see with the same named service, because they'd have to use my computer as their domain name server...

So I added a line like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 192.168.0.111
    ServerAlias MY.IP.XXX.XX
    DocumentRoot /home/work/wa.net/cvalley
</VirtualHost>
```

Where "MY.IP.XXX.XX" is my public IP address.

This works as expected, when you hit my IP address from a public network you see the site that lives in /home/work/wa.net/cvalley.

**UPDATE -- clarifying point of confusion**
The point of confusion that I have is that there are public IP addresses in my logs in the "for.us" sites, in addition to the "wa.net" sites. I would expect the "wa.net" to have some public IP access, but I don't understand how public bots are getting through to the "for.us" sites.

I would have expected it to be impossible to access **the "for.us"** sites in my network, unless the public user somehow figured out what I'm calling my ServerAliases, and is mimicing my domain set up...

How can public traffic be hitting my **"for.us"** sites? How can I recreate this kind of access?

Here are some examples of public IP's hitting my VirtualHost sites:

**Update -- better description of log**

this log shows activity in the **"for.us"** VirtualHost -- I would have expected activity to only exist in the **"wa.net"** domain, where I do have expected logs

```
162.253.66.76 - - [15/Aug/2014:19:20:47 -0600] "GET /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 404 1004 "-" "-"
162.253.66.74 - - [16/Aug/2014:10:50:28 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 262 "-" "masscan/1.0 (https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan)"
185.4.227.194 - - [16/Aug/2014:11:16:45 -0600] "GET http://24x7-allrequestsallowed.com/?PHPSESSID=1rysxtj500143WQMVT%5E_NAZ%5BQ HTTP/1.1" 200 262 "-" "-"
101.226.254.138 - - [16/Aug/2014:13:32:14 -0600] "HEAD / HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "-"
162.253.66.74 - - [16/Aug/2014:14:26:19 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 262 "-" "masscan/1.0 (https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan)"
212.129.2.119 - - [16/Aug/2014:16:00:51 -0600] "HEAD / HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "-"
91.240.163.111 - - [16/Aug/2014:18:34:32 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 262 "-" "masscan/1.0 (https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan)"
162.253.66.74 - - [16/Aug/2014:19:02:53 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 262 "-" "masscan/1.0 (https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan)"
122.226.223.69 - - [17/Aug/2014:05:53:09 -0600] "GET http://www.k2proxy.com//hello.html HTTP/1.1" 404 1006 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)"
::1 - - [17/Aug/2014:10:19:26 -0600] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.6 (Linux/SUSE) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.4.20 (internal dummy connection)"
162.209.65.196 - - [17/Aug/2014:15:31:53 -0600] "HEAD / HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "-"
111.206.199.163 - - [18/Aug/2014:11:12:56 -0600] "HEAD / HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "-"
37.187.180.168 - - [18/Aug/2014:15:40:00 -0600] "HEAD / HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "-"
62.210.38.226 - - [18/Aug/2014:18:35:16 -0600] "HEAD / HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "-"
```

Is there anything that I can do to reliably deny public access by default, but allow it only in one VirtualHost?

Comment: From that log file, what exactly shows the VirtualHosts being accessed?

Comment: As far as I can tell, that log just shows GET requests for / and a few items that don't exist (hence the 404 status codes).  What are you seeing?

Comment: sorry -- I really messed up my question and left out an important detail. There are two primary domains. One of the "wa.net" subdomains is the one I have set up to be publicly accessible via my IP address. I also have "for.us" subdomains, which write to a different log. I don't understand why I'm seeing public activity in this "for.us" log, when only the "wa.net" VirtualHost is tied to my public IP. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both wa.net and for.us resolve to the same IP, so the network can't tell for which DNS domain an IP packet (and TCP segment and UDP datagram) is intended. For example, HTTP disambiguates network traffic addressed to the same IP by examining the HTTP Host: header to see the intended domain of the request (that's how virtual web hosting works), but named has no concept of the DNS address of incoming datagrams.

I'd suggest putting wa.net and for.us on different IP addresses and configuring both addresses on the physical interface. This should separate the traffic at the IP level, and the virtualization software can deliver the packets to the appropriate virtual interface.

Comment: Do you mean put them on different public IPs? Or different local IPs? I'd assuming that I cannot do more than one public IP, since this is just a home setup, where i have only one public IP. Is that correct?

Comment: You should put them on different local IPs. Make sure the domain server and web server work for your LAN are working properly, then if you want to make the web server visible to the outside world, you can forward port 80 from your router to the web server's local IP.

Answer (score 3):

`for.us` is the first VirtualHost making it the "default" VirtualHost, so any petition that has no `Host` header (or not matches any of the other VirtualHosts) will end up there.

`HTTP/1.0` does not require `Host` header to work so it goes for the default VH.

---

EDIT: If it is a home setup, quickest solution for that case is moving the "public" Virtual Host to the top, so any connection defaults for that site.

Remember that for a NameVirtualHost you will have always a "default" VirtualHost if the Host header is not present or does not match any of your configured Names/Alias (the first VirtualHost defined for that IP)

Also, I would configure the ServerName directives to the value you are asigning to each ServerAlias and not using ServerAlias in your case. ServerName is intended to distinguish between which VirtualHost should be used if you set up a NameVirtualHost, so having the same value in all ServerName is not doing any good. ServerAlias is used to mark additional names (for example, `ServerName hostname` `ServerAlias hostname.domain.com`

Note that if your coworkers edit their `/etc/hosts` and add entries like `fmb.wa.net MY.IP.XXX.XX`, `postrecord.wa.net MY.IP.XXX.XX`, etc, they would get **any** site on your web server. You could block that with `Block`, `Allow` and `Order` directives, but entries with error code 403 would still appear on your access_log.

---

Finally, to resolve this issue properly and since there are plenty private IP available for you to use, I would do the following:

- First, asign one additional IP to your OpenSuse. Your current primary IP would be used for your internal server, and the new one for the internal and public server.

  - Locate `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth*`. Should be only one file if your server only has a single network card.
  - Edit it and add this lines (adjunt them to your convenience):

.

```
IPADDR1='192.168.0.112'
NETMASK1='255.255.255.0'
LABEL1='0'
```

- Restart the network: `/etc/init.d/network restart`
- Change your current `<VirtualHost *:80>` for `<VirtualHost 192.168.0.111:80>` except for you public VirtualHost, which should have instead `<VirtualHost 192.168.0.112:80>`
- Restart apache
- Edit your `named` to point the "public" name to the new IP if neccesary (for your internal use)
- Change the NAT you probably have at the router to point to the new IP.

With that configuration, from your public IP they would only get contents from the VirtualHost with IP 192.168.0.112

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I have other virtual hosts that are not getting public traffic. I wondered why for.us was the only one (in addition to the specific wa.net subdomain, which I want to get public traffic)

Comment: i wish i could give 2 answers the check mark

Comment: Added a explicit solution